# Remove everything right of a match in a variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable that I am handling in PHP and need to delete everything in it after a (known) match of characters, the length before the match and after vary in size. I'm not sure how to do this, for example:

```
$variable = "1234356ABCtreecar"
```

The next content of $variable could be:

```
$variable = "654321123456ABCcartreehouse"
```

The **ABC** part would always be present in the content of the variable, which varies in size dynamically, I just need to 'keep' everything before ABC in the variable and disregard everything after, so to end with the content of $variable in the two above examples as:

```
$variable = "123456"
```

and

```
$variable = "654321123456"
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Comment: http://php.net/strpos, http://php.net/substr

Comment: $test = explode("ABC", $variable);$variable=$test[0];

Comment: Sorry, my title was incorrect, I meant 'right of' a match, not 'eft of' the match...

Comment: @Mihai Thank you, that works perfectly for me, can you put it as an answer for me to accept it please? Thanks

Comment: This question is locked so this is not possible,good luck with you php learning.